# Average of each consecutive segment in a list

Tags: python, list, numpy, average

I have a list:

```
sample_list = array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16])
```

I want to calculate the average of every, say 4 elements. But not 4 elements separately, rather the first 4:

```
1,2,3,4
```

followed by:

```
2,3,4,5
```

followed by:

```
3,4,5,6
```

and so on.

The result will be an array or list of average between every 4 elements in the first list.

Output:

```
array([2.5, 3.5, 4.5, ...])
```

My attempt:

```
sample_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
splits = 4

def avgerage_splits(data):
    datasum = 0
    count = 0 
    for num in data:
        datasum += num
    count += 1
    if count == splits: 
        yield datasum / splits
        datasum = count = 0
if count: 
    yield datasum / count

print(list(average_splits(sample_list)))

[1.5, 3.5, 5.5, 7.5, 9.5, 11.0]
```

This is not the output I need as this calculates the average of every 4 elements before moving onto a new set of 4 elements. I want to only move one element up in the list and calculate the average of those 4 and so on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `numpy` is an option a simple way to achieve this is to use [`np.convolve`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html), which can be used to compute a *rolling mean* when convolving with an array of [`np.ones`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html):

```
import numpy as np
sample_list = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16], dtype=float)

w = 4
np.convolve(sample_list, np.ones(w), 'valid') / w
```

**Output**

```
array([ 2.5,  3.5,  4.5,  5.5,  6.5,  7.5,  8.5,  9.5, 10.5, 11.5, 12.5,
   13.5, 14.5])
```

---

**Details**

[`np.convolve`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) is performing a [discrete convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution) between the two input arrays. In this case `np.ones(w)`, which will be an array of as many ones as the specified window length (4 in this case) `array([1., 1., 1., 1.])` and `sample_list`.

The following list comprehension aims to replicate the way `np.convolve` is computing the output values:

```
w = 4
np.array([sum(ones*sample_list[m:m+w]) for m in range(len(sample_list)-(w-1))]) / w 

array([ 2.5,  3.5,  4.5,  5.5,  6.5,  7.5,  8.5,  9.5, 10.5, 11.5, 12.5,
   13.5, 14.5])
```

So at each iteration it will take the inner product between the array of ones and the current  *window* of `sample_list` .

Bellow is an example of how the first outputs are computed so that its a little clearer. Note that in this case the used mode specified for the convolution is `valid`, which means that, the overlap is specified to be always complete:

```
[1,1,1,1]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8...]
= (1*1 + 1*2 + 1*3 + 1*4) / 4 = 2.5
```

And the following as:

```
  [1,1,1,1]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8...]
= (1*2 + 1*3 + 1*4 + 1*5) / 4 = 3.5
```

And so on, yielding as mentioned earlier a  *moving average*  of `sample_list`.

Comment: Can you explain what the np.ones() does?

Comment: Yes this was very helpful. The 'moving average' is exactly what I was looking for. Upvoted and accepted. Thank you very much.

Comment: With `numpy.convolve` one can also do the following `new_list = np.convolve(sample_list, np.ones(4)/4, mode='valid')` would also do the work.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a one-line list comprehension:

```
avgs = [sum(sample_list[i:i + splits]) / splits for i in range(len(sample_list) - splits + 1)]
```

Of course, replace the square brackets with round brackets if you want a generator.

Answer (score 1):

You can map the function `mean()` to zipped iterators:

```
from statistics import mean
from itertools import islice

l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]

zip_iter = zip(*(islice(l, i, None) for i in range(4)))
list(map(mean, zip_iter))
# [2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5, 10.5, 11.5, 12.5, 13.5, 14.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

As a new programmer with little to no knowledge of most of python modules, here is an another solution. 4 is the number of splits. it can always be adjusted any number of splits you want. While 3 in (Len(nlis) - 3) is 4 - 1. so replace 3 with your number of splits - 1.

```
nlis = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]

summation = []
ave = []
for a in range(len(nlis)- 3):
    summation = sum(nlis[a:a+4])
    ave.append(summation/4)
print(ave)

# [2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5, 10.5, 11.5, 12.5, 13.5, 14.5]
```