# How to calculate the avearge of every 4 elements in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

sample_list = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16])

```
Required to take the average of every 4 
like 1,2,3,4 average is 2.5
followed by 5,6,7,8 is 6.5
followed by 9,10,11,12 is 10.5
followed by 13,14,15,16 is 14,5
```

expexted output:

```
[2.5, 6.5, 10.5, 14.5]
```

so far i tried with refering this questions
[Average of each consecutive segment in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54620614/average-of-each-consecutive-segment-in-a-list)

[Calculate the sum of every 5 elements in a python array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42444046/calculate-the-sum-of-every-5-elements-in-a-python-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `reshape`. In following example reshape(-1, 4) means 4 elements per row

```
import numpy as np

sample_list = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16])

print(np.mean(sample_list.reshape(-1, 4), axis=1))
```

output

```
[2.5, 6.5, 10.5, 14.5]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to do that. Considering that `sample_list` looks like the following

```
sample_list = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16])

[Out]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16])
```

Will leave below two options that will allow one to calculate the average of every 4 elements in the numpy array.

---

**Option 1**

```
newlist = [sum(sample_list[i:i+4])/4 for i in range(0, len(sample_list), 4)]

[Out]: [2.5, 6.5, 10.5, 14.5]
```

---

**Option 2**

Using [`numpy.mean`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html)

```
newlist = [np.mean(sample_list[i:i+4]) for i in range(0, len(sample_list), 4)]

[Out]: [2.5, 6.5, 10.5, 14.5]
```